# Embedding a database in VS Express 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have found that SQL Server Compact has been discontinued and that SQL Server Express should be used instead. I have been trying to get it working but have failed so far - I need to use it the same way as SQL Server CE - i.e. to insert a local DB into my app so that the DB will be used automatically wherever my app is deployed (no installation of SQL Server etc.). But I just cannot seem to find the way.

Comment: SQL Server Express - as any other server-based SQL Server version (anything but SQL Server CE) - has to be installed separately. There's no provision and no support by Microsoft to include the complete SQL Server installation into your own installer.

Comment: marc_c: yes, I was hoping that with discontinuation of SQLCE there will be an adequate alternative built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looking for an embedded database.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database

I would recommened

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)
 and its .net wrapper is [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

Comment: Thank you. Also if I get it right, there is no entirely built-in solution in VS2013? I mean, I need the app to be stand-alone with no need to install anything.

Comment: SQLite is stand alone, just need the path of the file, no need to install anything.

Comment: Yes but even the path to the file..I would need the db to be internal as it was with SQLCE in VS, so end user did not even know there is a db behind the scenes. Or maybe I do not get it right :)

Comment: Even in SQLCE theres a db file, .sdf.

Comment: Right, but it is all handled internally. Also, in VS2013 there is no equivalent not requiring any wrappers etc.?

Comment: wrapper is just a dll reference, the source code is available so you can use that as well.